# clojure split collection in chunks of increasing size

Tags: clojure, iteration, take

Hi I am a clojure newbie,

I am trying to create a function that splits a collection into chunks of increasing size something along the lines of

```
(apply #(#(take %) (range 1 n)) col)
```

where n is the number of chunks

example of expected output:
with n = 4 and col = (range 1 4)

```
(1) (2 3) (4)
```

with n = 7 and col = (range 1 7)

```
(1) (2 3) (4 5 6) (7)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
(defn partition-inc
  "Partition xs at increasing steps of n" 
  [n xs] 
  (lazy-seq 
    (when (seq xs) 
      (cons (take n xs) 
            (partition-inc (inc n) (drop n xs))))))

; (println (take 5 (partition-inc 1 (range))))
; → ((0) (1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8 9) (10 11 12 13 14))
```

Or if you want to have more influence, you could alternatively provide
a sequence for the sizes (behaves the same as above, if passed `(iterate inc 1)` for `sizes`:

```
(defn partition-sizes
  "Partition xs into chunks given by sizes"
  [sizes xs]
  (lazy-seq
    (when (and (seq sizes) (seq xs))
      (let [n (first sizes)]
        (cons (take n xs) (partition-sizes (rest sizes) (drop n xs)))))))

; (println (take 5 (partition-sizes (range 1 10 2) (range))))
; → ((0) (1 2 3) (4 5 6 7 8) (9 10 11 12 13 14 15) (16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24))
```

Comment: can you explain what each step does ?

Comment: Builds a lazy sequence by taking increasing chunks from the provided xs, "recurs" on the rest

Answer (score 2):

An eager solution would look like

```clj
(defn partition-inc [coll]
  (loop [rt [], c (seq coll), n 1]
    (if (seq c)
      (recur (conj rt (take n c)) (drop n c) (inc n))
      rt)))
```

Answer (score 2):

another way would be to employ some clojure sequences functions:

```
(->> (reductions (fn [[_ x] n] (split-at n x))
                 [[] (range 1 8)]
                 (iterate inc 1))
     (map first)
     rest
     (take-while seq))

;;=> ((1) (2 3) (4 5 6) (7))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach...

```
(defn growing-chunks [src]
  (->> (range)
       (reductions #(drop %2 %1) src)
       (take-while seq)
       (map-indexed take)
       rest))

(growing-chunks [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i])
;; => ((:a) (:b :c) (:d :e :f) (:g :h :i))
```